# Reference YAML Node using method parameter

Tags: ruby, yaml, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I load a yaml, and need to define a scope for it, to reference a specific node.

```
myYaml = YAML.load_file('myfile.yml').with_indifferent_access
```

Normally, I can just do

```
myYaml[:first_node][:first_child][:second_child]
```

However, I wanted to pass the path to a method to scope it for me. I am struggling to do something like this..

```
scope_path = [:first_node,:first_child,:second_child]

def scope(scope_path)
 myYAML[scope_path]
end
```

# So I need code to convert my scope_path parameter to

```
myYaml[:first_node][:first_child][:second_child]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple use [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
myYaml.dig(:first_node, :first_child, :second_child)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the splat operator (`*`) might be useful for OP's use case: `def scope(scope_path); MY_YAML.dig(*scope_path); end`.